# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue with API

Tags: google-app-engine

I have written a pretty simple API in PHP and am running it as a service (https://protoapi-dot-rehash-148415.appspot.com/events/).

When I try to load a data grid with the JSON from the API, I am getting the dreaded "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error on the page on which I want to consume the JSON. (http://proto-angular-dot-rehash-148415.appspot.com/events.php)

I've tried a couple of different methods to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" to the app.yaml file and to the header in the PHP file that produces the API. I think it doesn't work in the yaml because you cannot apply http_headers to dynamic files, and it doesn't work in the file because of the compression.

Is there any other way to make this work, short of putting the API and the app in the same service? I'd hate to do that because I am using mod_rewrite for the API and it will probably cause chaos on my app.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

-Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header won't do any good unless you add it server-side, on the events API. The server is what dictates CORS permissions. You could send it messages or files all day with the right headers at the top and it will just ignore them. The allow-origin header has to come from the server to allow the cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) to take place.

I would recommend prepending the header in the function that offers up the API or handles the requests. Your events API spits out a lot of JSON. Right before that JSON, have your API spit out the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and you should be all set.

As a sanity check you can also try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` and see if that helps. Based on your comment about the Content-Type header, this may be part of the problem. It should be added the same way as the other one; have your API send it prior to your events JSON on its own line (put a `\n` to make a new line inside the string literal).

Comment: Hey Tim. I actually am placing `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in the events API. I loaded the file in Postman and it appears that Google Apps Engine is stripping off the HTTP headers ... it comes across without the content-type header for JSON that I placed there and is replaced with a content-type header for GZIP. Looks like some sort of resource compression is taking place. I'll have to follow up with the GAE team on this one. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Do you also have an Access-Control-Allow-Headers header? I always have to specifically allow Content-Type headers on all my web services or they are automatically stripped as you said.

Comment: Never heard of that. Please, tell me more. I've only seen it available in Java apps in GAE.

Comment: It's something to try at least for a sanity check. I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: I finally found the problem. PHP was sticking a line return at the beginning of the file. Once I cleared the line return, it started working fine.